# Redirect not working on PWA website, when clicking on web push notifications on iOS using OneSignal

Tags: ios, reactjs, push-notification, onesignal

I am sending web push notification using OneSignal.
when sending notification to the PWA in iOS, then click on notification some time redirect not work

Expected result :
On clicking notification it should redirect to the target page of website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.